# how do i get more frames per second from this jogl program?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, vbo, frame-rate

trying to get more fps from this jogl program. theoretical fps is very high, but actual fps is low. jvisualvm says that most (over 90%) of the time is spent in AWTAnimatorImpl.display() & GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl().

```
package stanalone;
import static java.awt.Color.cyan;
import static java.awt.Color.magenta;
import static java.awt.Color.white;
import static java.awt.Color.yellow;
import static java.awt.Color.red;
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.min;
import static java.lang.Math.signum;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_FLOAT;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_FRONT;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_LEQUAL;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_NICEST;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_POINTS;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL.GL_WRITE_ONLY;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL2ES1.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT;
import static javax.media.opengl.GL2GL3.GL_FILL;
import static javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc.GLLightingFunc.GL_SMOOTH;
import static javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc.GLMatrixFunc.GL_MODELVIEW;
import static javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc.GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;
import javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc.GLLightingFunc;
import javax.media.opengl.fixedfunc.GLPointerFunc;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.gl2.GLUT;
class Histogram {
    public Histogram() {
        this(10,0,1);
    }
    public Histogram(int bins,double low,double high) {
        this.bins=bins;
        bin=new int[bins];
        this.low=low;
        this.high=high;
        range=high-low;
    }
    public void add(double[] x) {
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            add(x[i]);
    }
    public void add(double x) {
        n++;
        sum+=x;
        final double x2=x*x;
        sum2+=x2;
        min=Math.min(min,x);
        max=Math.max(max,x);
        if(x>=high)
            overflows++;
        else if(x<low)
            underflows++;
        else {
            double val=x-low;
            int index=(int)(bins*(val/range));
            bin[index]++;
        }
    }
    public void clear() {
        for(int i=0;i<bins;i++)
            bin[i]=0;
        overflows=0;
        underflows=0;
        min=Double.MAX_VALUE;
        max=Double.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    public int n() {
        return n;
    }
    public double low() {
        return low;
    }
    public double high() {
        return high;
    }
    public double range() {
        return high()-low();
    }
    public int bins() {
        return bins;
    }
    public double min() {
        return n==0?Double.NaN:min;
    }
    public double max() {
        return n==0?Double.NaN:max;
    }
    public double sum() {
        return n==0?Double.NaN:sum;
    }
    public double mean() {
        return n==0?Double.NaN:sum/n;
    }
    public double variance() {
        return n==0?Double.NaN:sum2/n-mean()*mean();
    }
    public int bin(int index) {
        if(index<0)
            return underflows;
        else if(index>=bins)
            return overflows;
        else return bin[index];
    }
    public double maxDifference() {
        double max=0;
        for(int i=0;i<bins();i++)
            max=Math.max(max,Math.abs(bin(i)-n()/(double)bins())/(n()/(double)bins()));
        return max;
    }
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        sb.append((float)min()).append("<=").append((float)mean()).append("<=").append((float)max()).append(" ");
        sb.append(bin(-1)).append(",[");
        for(int i=0;i<bins;i++)
            sb.append(i>0?",":"").append(bin(i));
        sb.append("],").append(bin(bins));
        return sb.toString();
    }
    private int[] bin;
    private int n,bins,underflows,overflows;
    private final double low,high,range;
    private double min=Double.MAX_VALUE,max=Double.MIN_VALUE,sum,sum2;
}
class MyDataObject {
    MyDataObject(Point2D[] points) {
        this(points,white);
    }
    MyDataObject(Point2D[] points,Color color) {
        this.points=points;
        this.color=color;
    }
    Point2D[] points;
    Color color;
    static Point2D[] randomPoints(Random random,Point2D offset) {
        List<Point2D> l=new LinkedList<Point2D>();
        int n=nPoints/pieces.length;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            l.add(new Point2D.Double(offset.getX()+random.nextFloat(),offset.getY()+random.nextFloat()));
        return l.toArray(new Point2D[0]);
    }
    static MyDataObject[] pieces;
    static Color[] colors=new Color[]{cyan,magenta,yellow,white};
    static int nPoints=1000000;
}
class StandAlone implements GLEventListener {
    StandAlone(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        this.drawable=drawable;
        drawable.addGLEventListener(this);
        init();
    }
    void init() {
        nVbos=4;
        vertexBufferIndices=new int[nVbos];
        for(int i=0;i<vertexBufferIndices.length;i++)
            vertexBufferIndices[i]=-1;
        numberOFVertices=new int[nVbos];
        // drawAxes=true;
        MyDataObject.pieces=new MyDataObject[nVbos];
        for(int i=0;i<nVbos;i++) {
            Point2D offset=new Point.Double(min(0,signum(cos(PI/4+i*PI/2))),min(0,signum(sin(PI/4+i*PI/2))));
            MyDataObject.pieces[i]=new MyDataObject(MyDataObject.randomPoints(random,offset),MyDataObject.colors[i%MyDataObject.colors.length]);
        }
    }
    static void setupFrame(Component component) {
        setupFrame(component,defaultFps);
    }
    static void setupFrame(Component component,int fps) {
        component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(displayWidth,displayHeight));
        final FPSAnimator animator=new FPSAnimator((GLAutoDrawable)component,fps,true);
        final JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(component);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                new Thread() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        if(animator.isStarted())
                            animator.stop();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
        frame.setTitle(TITLE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        animator.start();
    }
    static void setup() {
        GLProfile glprofile=GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities glcapabilities=new GLCapabilities(glprofile);
        GLJPanel panel=new GLJPanel(glcapabilities);
        new StandAlone(panel);
        setupFrame(panel,200);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                setup();
            }
        });
    }
    private void createVbo(GL2 gl2,int[] n,int index) {
        if(!gl2.isFunctionAvailable("glGenBuffers")||!gl2.isFunctionAvailable("glBindBuffer")||!gl2.isFunctionAvailable("glBufferData")||!gl2.isFunctionAvailable("glDeleteBuffers")) { throw new RuntimeException("Vertex buffer objects not supported."); }
        gl2.glGenBuffers(1,vertexBufferIndices,index);
        // create vertex buffer data store without initial copy
        gl2.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexBufferIndices[index]);
        gl2.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,n[0]*3*Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT*2,null,GL.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }
    private static void storeVerticesAndColors(FloatBuffer floatbuffer,MyDataObject w) {
        for(Point2D p:w.points) {
            floatbuffer.put((float)p.getX()).put((float)p.getY()).put(0);
            floatbuffer.put((float)(w.color.getRed()/255.));
            floatbuffer.put((float)(w.color.getGreen()/255.));
            floatbuffer.put((float)(w.color.getBlue()/255.));
        }
        floatbuffer.rewind();
    }
    private void fillVertexBuffer(GL2 gl2,MyDataObject piece,int index) {
        // map the buffer and write vertex and color data directly into it
        gl2.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexBufferIndices[index]);
        ByteBuffer bytebuffer=gl2.glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,GL_WRITE_ONLY);
        FloatBuffer floatbuffer=bytebuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        storeVerticesAndColors(floatbuffer,piece);
        gl2.glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    }
    protected int createAndFillVertexBuffer(GL2 gl2,MyDataObject piece,int index) {
        int[] n=new int[]{piece.points.length};
        if(vertexBufferIndices[index]==-1)
            createVbo(gl2,n,index);
        fillVertexBuffer(gl2,piece,index);
        return n[0];
    }
    private void renderPiece(GLAutoDrawable drawable,int index) {
        final GL2 gl2=drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl2.glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GLLightingFunc.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
        gl2.glEnable(GLLightingFunc.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        // draw all objects in vertex buffer
        gl2.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexBufferIndices[index]);
        gl2.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl2.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl2.glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,6*Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT,0);
        gl2.glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,6*Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT,3*Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT);
        gl2.glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_FILL);
        gl2.glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,1*numberOFVertices[index]);
        // disable arrays once we're done
        gl2.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        gl2.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl2.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl2.glDisable(GLLightingFunc.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    }
    private void startTimeReporting() {
        t0=System.nanoTime();
        if(frame%reportPeriod==0)
            t0Frame=t0;
        if(frame>1) {
            double dt=(System.nanoTime()-t0Display);
            double millis=dt/1000000.;
            hDisplay.add(millis);
        }
    }
    void endTimeReporting() {
        double dt=(System.nanoTime()-t0);
        double millis=dt/1000000.;
        hRender.add(millis);
        if(++frame%reportPeriod==0) {
            System.out.println("average render time: "+hRender.mean()+" ms., max fps="+1000./hRender.mean());
            double dtFrames=System.nanoTime()-t0Frame;
            System.out.println("average time between calls to display: "+hDisplay.mean()+" ms., actual fps="+reportPeriod/(dtFrames/1000000.)*1000.);
            hRender.clear();
        }
        t0Display=System.nanoTime();
    }
    void update() {
        angle+=1;
    }
    @Override public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable,int x,int y,int width,int height) {
        System.out.println("super.reshape "+drawable);
        GL2 gl=drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        if(height==0)
            height=1;
        float aspect=(float)width/height;
        gl.glViewport(0,0,width,height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // glu.gluPerspective(45.0,aspect,0.1,100.0);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
    @Override public void init(final GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl=drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        glu=new GLU();
        glut=new GLUT();
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        for(int i=0;i<nVbos;i++)
            numberOFVertices[i]=createAndFillVertexBuffer(drawable.getGL().getGL2(),MyDataObject.pieces[i],i);
    }
    @Override public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        update();
        if(doTimeReporting)
            startTimeReporting();
        GL2 gl=drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glRotated(angle,0,1,0);
        gl.glColor3d(1,1,1);
        for(int i=0;i<nVbos;i++)
            renderPiece(drawable,i);
        if(doTimeReporting)
            endTimeReporting();
    }
    @Override public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    final GLAutoDrawable drawable;
    double angle;
    int nVbos;
    int[] vertexBufferIndices;
    int[] numberOFVertices;
    Random random=new Random();
    final int reportPeriod=100;
    boolean doTimeReporting=true;
    long t0,t0Frame,t0Display;
    int frame;
    Histogram hRender=new Histogram(10,0,10),hDisplay=new Histogram(10,0,100);
    int fps=defaultFps;
    protected GLU glu;
    protected GLUT glut;
    protected static String TITLE="JOGL 2.0 Setup (GLJPanel)";
    protected static final int displayWidth=1024;
    protected static final int displayHeight=1024;
    protected static final int defaultFps=60;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ray, first switch to modern OpenGL. Second, calls such as `glMapBuffer` are *so* slow.

Comment: if i get back to that, i will try your suggestion. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, let me pass you a short [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle)

Comment: looks cleaner. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If most of the processing power is being put to use in the display code, chances are you're using too many vertices or complex texture calculations. Texture-wise, it is better to set the textures to objects on initialization where possible, so that you're program only has to load them once and it's done. For the vertices, be sure you aren't accidentally duplicating anything, and try to limit particle effects, because that can be very expensive with processing.

Comment: i only have 4 vbos with 250000 vertices and colors in each and no textures. render time is about .25 ms. for all of them. the time between calls to display is 37 ms.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand how OpenGL works. It's mostly useless to measure the time taken to wrap your OpenGL calls, as you are currently doing.

When you call an opengl command, it just puts the command into a processing queue and returns. The actual time it takes to *draw* the object is not the amount of time it takes you to issue all the draw calls.

If the time between calls to display is 37ms, than that's how long it takes the GPU to process all of the commands that you've queued to it.

Comment: i have an i3 with on chip graphics so that may be a problem. but 37 ms. seems sorta slow to me for 1000000 vertices and colors.